# How do I create a "platform" and "site" from CLI, using the drush extension provision

Tags: drush

I'm trying to figure out how to use [Provision](http://drupal.org/project/provision) to create new sites from the CLI.

I tried looking at what commands [Aegir](http://community.aegirproject.org/) normally passes to Provision when setting up a new platform and then a new site on that platform, but I haven't succesfully made it work from CLI.

Comment: Hopefully you are using drush 4.x; I happen to know that provision does not work with drush 5 yet.  Unfortunately, though, I do not know enough about provision to answer your question.

Comment: I noticed that as well, so that's not part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good article on this question in Aegir official documentation here:
http://community.aegirproject.org/content/manage-your-aegir-system-command-line